# Where do I get a bed for my child?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to adopt a local child (Lucy I think her name was) so I just bought a house in Whiterun. The problem is I don't have a child's bed.

Where would I buy or how do I make one?

Comment: First make sure you have the hearthfire DLC downloaded

Comment: @SPYBUG96 if I remember correctly, Lucy (nor any other child) doesn't have the dialogue option to adopt them until Hearthfire is installed.

Answer (score 4):

Go talk to Proventus Avenicci, the steward in Dragon's Reach. He will have a dialogue option to purchase a children's bedroom, that of course contains one.

[Further reading on him.](https://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Proventus_Avenicci)

[Futher reading on Breezehome.](https://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Breezehome)